# SSMS - Export long data into excel file without truncate data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting

I have a script that I wanna to export in an xls file.

Due to one of the fields is a product description, it has commas, csv file is not a good option.

I tried using DTS Wizard, but the descrpition field is nvarchar(8000) and DTS fails when tried to convert to varchar(255) or longtext.

the query result has 100k+ rows.

I tried to send the result to a .rpt file but the description field is truncated as well.

I tried to send the result to a .csv file but the description field is truncated as well.

I tried to do an OPENROWSET command in TSQL, but OLE DB provider throws an error.

Is there a way to get an excel result with the fields, without truncate any data, and without parsing a lot the fields (e.g. delete commas, add ", changing table data structure..) ?

Comment: If every instance is truncating the value (including SSRS) then sounds like the problem isn't Excel but your query (and it's truncating the text). That or you have more than 32,767 characters for a single cell.

Comment: grid view result is just fine, the issue is when I tried to save it in an xls file, rpt also is truncated

Comment: Definitely something is wrong. I've never had a problem of SSRS truncating to 255 characters (or SSIS in truth). Without knowing the actual steps to replicate this though, this is going to very difficult (impossible) to trouble shoot.

Comment: @MiguelRodrigoAlbarracin save it as a csv file. then open the csv file and save as .xlsx excel format. that way you will be able to save upto 1,048,576 records. if yoy save as .xls , you can only save a litte above 65,000 records

Comment: @JonWay *Hopefully* the OP isn't using `xls` anymore. `xlsx` has been about since 2007 and supports way more than 65,536 rows.

Comment: Export to .CSV, and open with any text editor, NOT Excel. See if it truncated or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @v1 varchar(2000);
set @v1 = replicate('ab',1000)
insert into i3 values (@v1)
select  * from i3
```

save it as a csv file. (Right click on the results and save as CSV).
When you open the csv file in excel I get the entire value.

You can also use BCP to export data from SQL Server to an CSV.

You can also use SSIS

You can use (in SSMS) by selecting the database you are exporting from in the Object Explorer window and right clicking choosing Tasks --> Export Data and follow the tabs.